# Bool in If-Statement

Tags: python, if-statement

```py
condition1 = False
condition2 = False

if condition1:
    print("condition1 is true")

elif condition2:
    print("condition2 is true")

else:
    print("both condition1 and condition2 are false")
```

Does the if respectively the else check automatically determine whether the bool of condition1 and condition2 is true or false without specifying that in the condition statement explicitly?

Comment: You don't need to add checks for bools in if statements, but due to how you have setup your code if condition1 and condition2 is true only "condition1 is true"  would be in the output since `elif` checks are only executed when the previous if/elif fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull, `else` works without any conditions (now you corrected your question).

Conditions in `if ... elif ... else` constructions are checked step by step.
It stops at the check block, where the condition is `True` (in your case, it could be when `condition1` or the next `condition2` is equal to `True`), and otherwise (when the condition was equal to `False`) it goes to the next check block. And the last `else` works only if all the previous conditions are not met (are equal to `False` - this is your case, while `condition1` and `condition2` are both equal to `False`).

Answer (score 0):

At the execution of the `if` block, the expression representing the condition is evaluated.

`condition1` is itself an expression:

```
>>> condition1
False
```

The following is also an expression

```
>>> condition1 == True
False
```

So both can be used as condition in an if block

```
if [condition] :
   ...
```

In practice, if you have a boolean variable, use it directly as a condition. If you want to check `condition1==False`, then use `if not condition1`

```
>>> not condition1
True
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, your question wasn't very clear but if I understand correctly, you are asking if you need you need to explicitly put `== true` in the if conditions, right?

firstly, that would depend on what language you are using but most languages don't require you to put the `== true` if you pass a bool for the if condition.